# Initialize large array of structs

Tags: c

I need to store a lot of information about certain resolutions at some way, I would like to make a struct for this.

```
struct resolution{
    const char* name;
    const int width;
    const int height;
};
```

The problem is I need to store a lot of resolutions in some array of structs, but can't get this work properly (need to store 126 things to it 'manual', so no loops or that kind of stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to initialize the array to zero?

Comment: Give examples of what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried an initializer?

```
struct resolution {
  const char * name ;
  const int width ;
  const int height ;
}
  mylist[] = 
  {
    { "cga", 320, 240 },
    { "vga", 640, 480 },
    { "xga", 1024, 768 },
  } ;
```

As a bonus, you can store a sentinel at the end so any loop that reads these can stop on the value instead of keeping track of how long the list is:  Using something like:

```
{ NULL, 0, 0 }
```

So you can check if the `name` is `NULL` or the size, like this:

```
const struct resolution *  find_bysize( int w, int h )
{
  struct resolution * searchptr ;

  for (searchptr= mylist ; ( searchptr-> name ) ; searchptr ++ )
    { if (( searchptr-> width == w ) && (searchptr-> height == h )) { return searchptr ; } }
  return NULL ;  // not found
}
```

Comment: That would be fun for 126 elements. ;-)

Comment: Already tried that, but I copy pasted your code (you just forgot resolution befor mylist[] and it worked! Maybe I made a typing error. Thanks and sorry for the stupid question
@Fiddling Bits: no problem, I have them in CVS format so I can do it with a small script ;)

Comment: Oh, and if you're ever going to use visual C, don't leave on the trailing ',' after the last element.  My experience with the older versions was that the compiler tends to choke on it, even though its valid.  Another reason to add the sentinel, makes the special case when generating the table easy.

Comment: I'm using the online mbed compiler (for microcontrollers) and xCode for making programs for my mac. But thanks ;)